# executing a second command in a batch file

Tags: windows, google-chrome, batch-file

i have batch file that clears a value in the registry that is related to the usage block of chrome on a PC. every time i double click the batch file it will clear that value allowing an admin to use chrome. i have a user that needs to access an EPA website but can only on chrome. below is the code i tried to use but the second command after editing the registry does not run. it will never open a chrome webpage. i want their IE to stay default. i will set chrome's homepage to the page she needs for simplicity. how can i achieve the results i want?

```
REGEDIT4

; @ECHO OFF
; CLS
; REGEDIT.EXE /S "%~f0"
; EXIT

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\URLBlacklist]
"1"=- 
&
@echo off
start chrome.exe https://cdx.epa.gov/epa_home.asp
```

this is what i am trying to execute.

```
echo
reg delete HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\URLBlacklist /v 1 /f
echo done.

echo
start chrome.exe https://cdx.epa.gov/epa_home.asp
echo done.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
reg delete HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\URLBlacklist /v 1 /f
"C:\Program Files\SomeFolder\chrome.exe" https://cdx.epa.gov/epa_home.asp
```

Your code is crazy.

I don't use non programmable browsers. You'll have to fix the path. This works using WINDOWS.

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" https://cdx.epa.gov/epa_home.asp
```

Comment: i didn't write it. i was just trying to add the open chrome part to it

Comment: does not open webpage

Comment: @Edgar He included a fake path to Chrome that will need to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

**remove.reg**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\URLBlacklist]
"1"=-
```

**remove.bat**

```
echo Removing 1st entry in URL blacklist...
regedit /S remove.reg
echo done.
echo Opening blocked site...
start chrome.exe https://cdx.epa.gov/epa_home.asp
echo done.
```

Comment: this seems to work. i cant tell if it deleted that  value i have to wait til it reappears and try running it again but the regedit stays open. is there a "regedit /C" ?

Comment: It did not stay open for me.  Close it and try again?

Comment: And for what it's worth, the best solution would be combining my answer with Noodle's so you don't need the extra `.reg` file.  Just replace his second line with the `start chrome.exe` line you originally had.  `reg delete` is much cleaner than using regedit.

Comment: tried on a different PC made the user a local admin. and loging in as her and i put the script that worked onto her desktop and it opens the web page fine but the key never gets deleted

Comment: You'll have to run the command prompt with elevated privileges.  (Right click - Run as administrator).  Did you try that?

Comment: the user has local admin privleges should i not have to do that?

Comment: i ran as admin anyways and did not delete the entry. i updated what i am execturing

Comment: i even tried to make a bat file to call the original that did work and then calling a bat file that opens the page but the item deletes but the page doesnt open

Answer (score 0):

Whilst bizarre, it can be done in the style of the original

```
REGEDIT4

; @ECHO OFF
; CLS
; REGEDIT.EXE /S "%~f0"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\URLBlacklist]
"1"=- 

; start chrome.exe https://cdx.epa.gov/epa_home.asp
; EXIT
```

; indicates a comment in registry files but appears to be ignored when at the start of a batch file line.